# Deploying Azure Functions to a specific function within multiple without overwriting the others

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-functions

I have 2 Function Apps in Production with several functions each.
When I want to deploy the VSCODE project of specific Function (project) the prompt asks me to choose the Function App to deploy to, and after I'm choosing the right one - it actually deploys the **same** set of functions to the other Function App as well.

[image: 2 Function Apps]

These are the functions inside - it's always identical even deploying from different project:

[image: Identical functions inside]

I'm trying to figure what am I missing here.
Any help is appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Solution is found.
It happened to be that the configuration of **WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE** had the same value for both Function Apps.

Changing that to a unique value per App fixed the issue and now we can deploy each bundle to the relevant App.